# Python - Problem in understanding Monostate design pattern code

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have seen this peice of code in a tutorial regarding Monostate design pattern in Python:

```
class BookShelf:
    _shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self, number_of_books):
        self.number_of_books = number_of_books

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        object_ = super().__new__(cls)
        object_.__dict__ = cls._shared_state
        return object_
```

When I tested this code, it works as the class addresses are different while the `number_of_books` is shared between them. I don't understand how the `number_of_books` is passed to the `_shared_state`. What I understand from the code is that `_shared_state` is passed to the new objects' `__dict__` attribute. So how is the state actually shared between instances when `__dict__` is never passed to `_shared_state`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `_shared_state` is a class variable that is shared by all instances of a class.
- `__new__` method is responsible to create an instance of class, so you can use this method to customize object creation.
- `__dict__` is a dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes. Or in other words `__dict__` is the dictionary containing the class’s namespace;
- `__dict__` is overwritten by the same dictionary object `_shared_state`  for all created objects, hence they will all share and use the same `__dict__` object